# Type error with dictionary method mapping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am getting a `TypeError: states() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'column' and 'states_dict'` when i am trying to call the function "states" and I have tried to comment out states and i get a similar message for 'lang'

here are the initial dictionaries and data needed

```
import pandas as pd

data= [["English","john","smith","ohio","united states","tesla","test@gmail.com","manufacturing","National","Residental","","TRUE","FALSE"]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Communication_Language__c','firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'country', 'company', 'email', 'industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'customerSegment', 'Existing_Customer__c', 'GDPR_Email_Permission__c'])

lang_trans= {"English":"ENG", "French":"FR"}

states_dict= {"Alabama": "AL", "Alaska": "AK", "Arizona": "AZ", "Arkansas": "AR", "California": "CA", "Colorado": "CO", "Connecticut": "CT", "Delaware": "DE", "Florida": "FL", "Georgia": "GA", "Hawaii": "HI", "Idaho": "ID", "Illinois": "IL", "Indiana": "IN", "Iowa": "IA", "Kansas": "KS", "Kentucky": "KY", "Louisiana": "LA", "Maine": "ME", "Maryland": "MD", "Massachusetts": "MA", "Michigan": "MI", "Minnesota": "MN", "Mississippi": "MS", "Missouri": "MO", "Montana": "MT", "Nebraska": "NE", "Nevada": "NV", "New Hampshire": "NH", "New Jersey": "NJ", "New Mexico": "NM", "New York": "NY", "North Carolina": "NC", "North Dakota": "ND", "Ohio": "OH", "Oklahoma": "OK", "Oregon": "OR", "Pennsylvania": "PA", "Rhode Island": "RI", "South Carolina": "SC", "South Dakota": "SD", "Tennessee": "TN", "Texas": "TX", "Utah": "UT", "Vermont": "VT", "Virginia": "VA", "Washington": "WA", "West Virginia": "WV", "Wisconsin": "WI", "Wyoming": "WY", "District of Columbia": "DC", "Washington DC": "DC"}
```

here is all of the functions I have

```
# this is supposed to make str.title() all the columns in the dictionary with the function 'capitalize'

def capitalize(col):
    if col.notna().any():
        return col.str.title()
    return col

#this is supposed to replace the values in the 'communication_lang_c' column with the abbreviated value found in the lang_trans dictionary

def lang(df_lang, column, lang_dict):
    for k, v in lang_dict.items():
        df_lang[column] = df[column].replace(k,v)
    return df_lang

#this is similar to lang where its supposed to replace the values in df[states] with the abbreviated value found in states_dict

def states(df_states, column, states_dict):
    for i,j in states_dict.items():
        df_states[column]=df[column].replace(i,j)
    return df_states

def req_cols (col):
    #TODO
    return col

def valid(col):
    #TODO
    return col
```

here is the method dictionary

```
parsing_map={
"firstName": [req_cols, capitalize],
"lastName": [req_cols, capitalize],
"state":[valid, states,capitalize],
"Communication_Language__c": lang,
"country": [req_cols,valid,capitalize],
"company":[req_cols],
"email":[req_cols],
"industry":[valid,capitalize],
"SME_Vertical__c":[valid],
"System_Type__c":[valid,capitalize],
"AccountType":[valid,capitalize],
"customerSegment":[capitalize],
"Existing_Customer__c":[req_cols],
"GDPR_Email_Permission__c":[req_cols]
}
```

and finally here is where i call all of the functions, this is where i think my error is coming from

```
for col_name, fns in parsing_map.items():
    for fn in fns:
        df[col_name] = fn(df[col_name])

#transforming communication_lang_c
df = lang(df, 'Communication_Language__c' ,lang_trans)

#transforming state
df = states(df, 'state', states_dict)
```

I am getting `TypeError: states() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'column' and 'states_dict'` but I am not sure what this is telling me.

How do i run the state and lang function so they replace the value in the df with the one mapped to them in the dictionary without getting a `"TypeError: states() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'column' and 'states_dict'"`

my desired output

```
data= [["ENG","John","Smith","OH","United States","tesla","test@gmail.com","Manufacturing","National","Residential","","TRUE","FALSE"]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Communication_Language__c','firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'country', 'company', 'email', 'industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'customerSegment', 'Existing_Customer__c', 'GDPR_Email_Permission__c'])
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are iterating through `parsing_map.items()`, when you get to `col_name="state"`, `fns=[valid, states,capitalize]`, so when you iterate through fns then call `fn(df[col_name])`, `fn=states` which means you are calling the `states` function with one argement, but the way you defined the function it requires three arguments,  see `def states(df_states, column, states_dict)`.

Things to note here: **positional arguments** refers to argument for which there is no specified default value, so you are required to input them. The function will detect these arguments based on the order in which they are input, hence *positional*. **keyword arguments** means that there is a default value specified so it is not required that you include those arguments when you make a call.

In your example, if you wished to be able to call `states` with only one argument, you would have to make the remaining two keyword arguments.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
def states(df_states, column="state", states_dict=states_dict):
    for i,j in states_dict.items():
        df_states[column]=df[column].replace(i,j)
    return df_states
```

p.s.
There is a second error in your code which is that some of the values in your `parsing_map` are just functions not lists (see `"company": req_cols`) so you won't be able to iterate through

Comment: If I make the single functions just functions as opposed to list then I get a type error is there a way around this? So I can iterate functions

Comment: yes, that is what I was commenting about with the `p.s.` part... give it a shot to see what you can fix, I can help if you have more questions:)

Comment: you have two options, one is something like `"company": [req_cols]`, the other is as you iterate through `parsing_map` check `if not isinstance(fns, list):\nfns=[fns]`

Comment: I will update that code, interestingly now I get ` keyError lang` track back to df[col_name]=fn and df_lang[column]= df_lang[column].replace

Comment: maybe chage `fn(df[col_name])` to something like `fn(df, col_name)`? It looks like `states` and `lang` functions are set up to take in the dataframe and the column name separately. Although this wouldn't work for `req_col`. Basically, if you want to be able to iterate through `parsing_map` and call your functions, all your function need to have some way of taking in the same inputs or none at all